# ArcGIS Portal inaccessible externally on AWS esri instance

Tags: redirect, arcgis

I've been installing our very own ArcGIS Enterprise instance on AWS.
The instance I chose is ArcGIS Enterprise on Ubuntu.
It is important to mention that this installation was conducted without using Cloudbuilder. I know it is a tool that automates the process but I was introduced to it only after I have already started to attack my current instance problems head-on. So, please don't advise me to restart the whole process from scratch using it.

The current status of my instance is that my ArcGIS Server is working. I can access it, upload services and we have already started using it in out Staging environment.

I have authorized all of the software on the server and verified it is licensed. The Portal for ArcGIS is my main problem.
Whenever I try to access it externally(from my office computer) it seems to redirect to the internal IP for some reason, and then times out on that request.
for example typing(from my browser):

```
https://[dns address]:7443/arcgis/home
```

redirects to:

```
https://[internal IP]:7443/arcgis/home
```

and this times out. (...took too long to respond error)

The funny thing is I can access the portaladmin area.
it's only the portal itself which doesn't work.

Also, another curious thing is that if I type without using the ports, I can access a window but exceptions are thrown in the browser.
For example:

```
https://[dns address]/arcgis
```

This will lead to a window where the ArcGIS world icon can be seen but nothing else loads and there are exceptions for "resource not found" 404 on some of the components of this page.

Any ideas? What further information should I include to answer this question?
I've looked everywhere but Esri's documentation is not very forthcoming with examples and information to understand what it is I did wrong.
Also, I don't think this is a ArcGIS software issue. It looks like this might be a proxy issue. Anyone else experienced something like this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.
It was a combination of two problems:

1. Tomcat that was running the web adaptor service was crashing because of an entirely different and unrelated issue.
2. The Portal was missing a web adaptor configuration and therefore did not have the WebContext property set with the web adaptor URL.

After fixing both of these problems, I was able to access the portal correctly.